# How to access the value of a dynamically generated Go Template Variable

Tags: go, go-templates

Very new to Go and using range. I am attempting to generate a variable name using the values from range and would like to get the value of the dynamically generated variable. Here is my code

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "os"
        "text/template"
)

type EnvironmentCluster[] struct {
    cluster string
    env     string
}

const tmpl = `
{{$application_configuration := "generic config"}}
{{$application_development_configuration := "dev_config"}}
{{$application_stage_configuration := "stage_config"}}

{{range $cluster, $env := .}}
    {{$config := (printf "application_%s_configuration" $cluster) }}
    Cluster is {{$cluster}}, env is {{$env}}, config is {{$config}}
{{end}}
`

func main() {
    clusterEnv := map[string]string{
        "development": "dev",
        "stage": "prod",
    }

        t := template.New("EnvironmentCluster template")

        t, err := t.Parse(tmpl)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Parse: ", err)
                return
        }

        err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, clusterEnv)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Execute: ", err)
                return
        }
}
```

When I run the above code, I am getting the following

```
Cluster is development, env is dev, config is application_development_configuration

    
Cluster is stage, env is prod, config is application_stage_configuration
```

But my expectation is to see the actual value of `config` being printed like this -

```
Cluster is development, env is dev, config is dev_config

    
Cluster is stage, env is prod, config is stage_config
```

Any help/pointers? Looking for ways to access outside range variables to be used inside the range in go-templates.

Comment: Typo?  Use `(printf "%s_config" $cluster)` to print instead of `(printf "application_%s_configuration" $cluster)`.

Comment: @ceriseLimon Its not a typo - I am attempting to generate the variable name which is either `application_development_configuration` or `application_stage_configuration`. I would not know the value stored in that variable